# how can I get the AUFS kernel module on a Google Compute Engine (GCE) kernel?

Tags: kernel-module, google-compute-engine, docker

The latest compute engine kernel is a 3.3.8 variant, and does not appear to have AUFS support configured in. The kernel is distributed outside the main file system image (I am using the default Debian image), and the Debian image does not appear to include AUFS as a module.

1. Is there already a binary module for AUFS on GCE available somewhere?
2. If not, how would I go about compiling a module against the kernel provided by the system?

My end goal is to get the Docker LXC manager running, and AUFS is a dependency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Google Compute Engine kernels do not currently support AUFS or allow dynamic module loading but I've submitted an internal feature request to address this need. Of course, that's not a commitment, just a way to ensure this gets considered for the future.

Comment: Now GCE is in GA and supports custom kernels

Comment: Yes, correct - here are instructions for running Docker on Google Compute Engine: http://docs.docker.io/en/master/installation/google/